# preg_replace doesn't remove everything between form tags, but on other page it does

Tags: php

I have the code below to filter out everything between `<script>` and `<form>` tags in a string.

```php
// $Ntext = input from contenteditable; //
$Ntext = preg_replace('#(<script.*?>).*?(</script>)#', '$1$2', $Ntext);
$Ntext = preg_replace('#(<form.*?>).*?(</form>)#', '$1$2', $Ntext);
```

After the code above I check `$Ntext` and everything between the script tags is removed. But everything between the form tags is **not** deleted.

The weird thing is that **I use this on other page and it works**, it does remove everything between the form tags. But now I'm making a new page, but with the other page as it's base. They are the same on 1 it's working on 1 not. I noticed the error and that's why **I added the script removal part to test and that is working**, but it's not removing everything between the form tags.

Comment: There's a great interactive regex tool that I use for visualising what is happening with my regex's (as I don't use them often and forget the tokens) https://regex101.com – You can paste your script tags into it and see how the regex handles it.

Comment: Try the `s` modifier so the dot character matches new lines: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php you might want to also use the `i` modifier too since the tag names don't need to be in all lowercase.  But note that parsing (X)HTML with a single regexp is generally discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Instead use a document parser that properly handles (X)HTML noisiness and oddities etc. There's plenty of php-based libraries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser. The most obvious brain-dead example of what can go wrong with your regex are things like this:

```html
<form>
<script>
document.write('<form method="post">blah</form>');
//</script>
doSomething();
</script>
<!-- </form> -->
<input type="text" name="foo"/>
</form>
```

But there are far more subtle problems that *will* (not might) break your code at some point.

Do it properly the first time.

```php
$nText = '<div class="foo"><form method="post"><p>Some Text</p><input name="foo"/></form></div><script src="bar"></script>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($nText, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("form") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = "";
}
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("script") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = "";
    if ($node->getAttribute("src")) {
        $node->setAttribute("src", "redacted");
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Output:

```
<div class="foo"><form method="post"></form><script src="redacted"></script></div>
```